# Why is my icons showing squares on Font Awesome?

Tags: html, css

Trying to figure out why icons are showing white icons. I have already tried changing 'fab' to 'fa' but no luck.  Has anyone else come across this problem using Font Awesome?

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">




<ul>
  <li><a><i class="fas fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
  <li><a><i class="fas fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
  <li><a><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
  <li><a><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

Check [working code snippet](https://codepen.io/nat-davydova/pen/b8d36f63765ed654c2165a62142bbc96).

In your code you have 2 issues:

1) `fas` and `fab` need to be changed to `fa`

2) all `<i>` items need to be of font-family fontawesome, and your code:

```
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
```

just rewrites their default styles and icons can't be rendered. Better don't use `*` selector with style rules like font-family to avoid such issues. So you can either remove these lines, or explicitly tell `<i>` tags to be of proper font-family, like in my code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is my icons showing squares on font awesome?

**many reason:**

- First of all, you reset the font-family, so no way to get the icone to show. , then :

  - you are using the wrong library (or the wrong class naming)
  - wrong class names for some

you can filter all of your   class  starting with `fa` to avoid overwritting the font-family that shows icons.

example below , filtering icon containers via the `:not()` selector, adding the good library and fixing class name for facebook and twitter.

```css
*:not([class^="fa"]) {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />





<ul>
  <li><a><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
  <li><a><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
  <li><a><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
  <li><a><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your style tag is overriding the font that fontawesome is providing to display the icons.

```
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Removing the `!important` will suffice.

Also the class to apply to the `<i>` tags is `fa` (not `fab` or `fas`)

Answer (score 0):

- font-awesome 4.x version CDN - `<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>`

  Live link - [Jsfiddle for 4.x version](https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/u9e5pndv/18/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</head>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

- font-awesome 5.x version CDN - `<i class="fas fa-facebook"></i>`

  Live link - [Jsfiddle for 5.x version](https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/u9e5pndv/20/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
</head>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
      <li><a><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
      <li><a><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like the following just wrong font awesome class for icon

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">   
<style>
    *{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

</style>
</head>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Wrong Version**

All you have to do is turn them all into fa-fa, then remove the font. You should use Font Awesome version 4.70.0 for this (shows the old youtube logo.):

`https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`.

If you don't want to do that, you'll have to go to the 5.12.0 version of Font Awesome, which I wouldn't want to do - just type the above link instead of the one in your code.
full code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">




<ul>
  <li><a><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
  <li><a><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
  <li><a><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
  <li><a><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```